# Problems creating a generic MVVM connector to CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mvvm, combine

First of all, sorry about the post length but I am very new to iOS and SwiftUI development and I don't want to miss any details. I did some small projects with Kotlin on Android and Flutter, so I had some experience in app development.

#### Context

I trying to create a simple app that persists the user data on CoreData and I trying to follow MVVM architecture to develop the app. I was inspired by the following [post](https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-and-coredata-the-mvvm-way-ab9847cbff0f) on Medium. And I have the following files:

- *DataSource.swift*: Class that abstracts the initialization of `NSPersistentContainer`.
- *Entity.swift*: Protocol for CoreData entity class standardization.
- *ProductEntity.swift*: Particular CoreData class definition that conforms *Entity* protocol.
- *Model.swift*: Class with Entity generic that abstracts the model instantiation and updating process.
- *ProductModel.swift*: Particular CoreData entity model definition that inherits *Model<ProductEntity>* (**where exception raises**).

#### The exception

I got an exception initializing the `ProductsModel` class (*ProductsModel.swift*, check it below) and I don't have any idea about where are the error source and its reason.

```sh
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors'
```

I hope you can give me some clues! :)

#### The code

**DataSource.swift**:

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

let defaultDatabase = "DB"

class DataSource {
    static let shared = DataSource()
    public let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(dbName: String = defaultDatabase) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: dbName)
        container.loadPersistentStores { (_, err) in
            if let error = err as NSError? {
                print("NSError \(error) - \(error.userInfo)")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
    func save() {
        do {
            print("Saving context")
            try self.container.viewContext.save()
            print("Successfully saved context")
        } catch {
            print("ERROR: \(error as NSObject)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity.swift**:

```swift
import CoreData

protocol Entity: NSFetchRequestResult {
    associatedtype CurrentEntity: NSManagedObject
    static var name: String { get }
}
```

**ProductEntity.swift**:

```swift
import os
import CoreData

@objc(ProductEntity)
public class ProductEntity: NSManagedObject, Entity {
    typealias CurrentEntity = ProductEntity
    static let name: String = "Product"
}

extension ProductEntity : Identifiable {
    public var ID: String {
        self.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
    }
}

extension ProductEntity {
    @NSManaged public var desc: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    @NSManaged public var price: Double
    @NSManaged public var rations: Int16
    @NSManaged public var shoppingList: NSSet?
}
```

**Model.swift**:

```swift
import Combine
import CoreData
import os

class Model<T: Entity>: NSObject, ObservableObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    var records = CurrentValueSubject<[T.CurrentEntity], Never>([])
    private let controller: NSFetchedResultsController<T.CurrentEntity>
    
    override init() {
        controller = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T.CurrentEntity>(entityName: T.name),
            managedObjectContext: DataSource.shared.container.viewContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil
        )
        
        super.init()
        
        controller.delegate = self
        
        do {
            try controller.performFetch()
            records.value = (controller.fetchedObjects ?? []) as [T.CurrentEntity]
        } catch {
            NSLog("Error: could not fetch objects")
        }
    }
    
    public func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        guard let records = controller.fetchedObjects as? [T.CurrentEntity] else { return }
        self.records.value = records
    }
    
    public func save() {
        DataSource.shared.save()
    }
}
```

**ProductModel.swift**:

```swift
import os

class ProductsModel: Model<ProductEntity> {
    static let shared: ProductsModel = ProductsModel() // <-- This line raise the exception
}
```

Comment: As the exception says, the `NSFetchRequest` that you pass to the `NSFetchedResultsController` must have at least one sort descriptor. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller. You could pass a sort key to your model initialiser.   Honestly, if you are just starting out you are probably making life hard for yourself trying to adopt MVVM unless you have a lot of experience with this on another platform. MVVM is not a natural fit for iOS, particularly if you are using UIKit unless you use Combine or a similar binding framework.

Answer (score 1):

`NSFetchedResultsController` is a tool which could manage your search results from Core Data. It needs at least one sort descriptor to maintain the list of your fetch request.
So you should improve the `NSFetchRequest` you defined like below to resolve the exception.

```swift
let req = NSFetchRequest<T.CurrentEntity>(entityName: T.name)
req.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "someKeyForSort", ascending: true)]
```

In addition, `"someKeyForSort"` is the name of a property of `T.CurrentEntity`. If `ProductEntity` is the type, "name" could be the key assuming you want `NSFetchedResultsController` to maintain the fetched results sorted by name in ascending order.